# Pasting text into a webview

Tags: android

in the default android browser, when you long-press on a textbox inside of a webpage you get a context menu showing several options, such as the ability to paste text into the textbox. How do I replicate this functionality with my own webview?

I looked in the android source code, specifically the code that handles context menu creation and found this:

```
     @Override
     public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

         ...

         WebView.HitTestResult result = webview.getHitTestResult();
         int type = result.getType();
         if (type == WebView.HitTestResult.EDIT_TEXT_TYPE) {
             // let TextView handles context menu
             return;
         }

         ...

    }
```

What the code means is that when the user long-presses on a "EDIT_TEXT_TYPE" ie. a textbox, the webview does nothing. Some magical "TextView" handles the context menu. Now I'm lost, how do I get this context menu to appear in my webview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `registerForContextMenu()`.  I know it works on ListView for sure but it also works on other views.

It should go something like this:

```
registerForContextMenu(yourWebView);

@Override
 public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

       //Code for "Paste";

     }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'll award you the answer since you pointed me in the right direction. I had some code that circumvents a bug in HTC devices in the onCreateContextMenu method that conflicted with the default android behavior to create a context menu for textboxes.